# swap nested list in haskell

Tags: haskell, nested-lists, hotswap

I want to swap a list like `(1,3,[2,4],5,[7,12,[14]])`

I know that in haskell types of a list should be the same so I confused how can I do this.

Should I use another data structure?
or I should define another data type?

for example swap 2 3 (1,3,[2,4],5,[7,12,[14]]) ==> (1,3,5,[2,4],[7,12,[14]])

Comment: Could you post expected output for your example? I am not sure if I understand question correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed such lists are not possible and it really is a tree you are looking at, for example something like this.

```
data NestedList a = Leaf a | Node [NestedList a]
```

Now you have to think what you really mean by `swap`. You can swap the top level lists, you can swap leaves and ...

Answer (score 1):

In your case it is not a list, but actually a tuple. Tuples are heterogenous containers, so that is why different types may be inside them. However, swapping elements in tuple is impossible to be written in generic way, at least with standard Haskell. I suggest operating on data pointed by Bryan.

Comment: Well actually there's a `[7,12,[14]]` inside the tuple, which isn't possible unless there is some crazy `Num` or `IsList` instance in scope.